# VBA (API) save SOLIDWORKS drawing as PDF in a set location

Tags: vba, api, pdf, save-as, solidworks

I am trying to figure out how to modify my PDF saving macro so that instead of saving the PDF in the same folder as drawing, it would save it to a set location that's written out in macro.

The code I am working with is:

```
Sub Save_PDF()

'Declare variables
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swExportPDFData As SldWorks.ExportPdfData
Dim strFilename As String
Dim status As Boolean
Dim errors As Long, warnings As Long

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

'Export to PDF if it is a drawing
If (swModel.GetType = swDocDRAWING) Then

strFilename = swModel.GetPathName
strFilename = Left(strFilename, Len(strFilename) - 6) & "pdf"

Set swExportPDFData = swApp.GetExportFileData(1)
swModel.Extension.SaveAs strFilename, 0, 0, swExportPDFData, 0, 0
End If

End Sub
```

Would someone, please, help me with this one?

Comment: Your code includes the filename in the address which should be avoided if possible. and that code gave a syntax error or something so now I have:
strFilename = "C:\Users\eduards\Desktop\TEST\" & Left(strFilename, Len(strFilename) - 6) & "pdf" and it doe nothing, no result and no error

Comment: As explained in OP I am trying to get the code modified so that it has a set directory to save the PDF of a drawing from SOLIDWORKS. What the code does now is saves PDF in the same location as the drawing file. There will be a logic for file naming which will always be different, but the location to save it always the same. That's the part I am trying to achieve at the moment

Comment: Ahh, sorry I didn't realize that part... yeah it's on the server. The current drawing location is also on that same server. Let's say address is "G:\45 Design"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the name of the file then concatenate with the rest of the path, and remove the unnecessary lines, like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Save_PDF()
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim strFilename As String
Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
If swModel.GetType <> swDocDRAWING Then MsgBox ("Error: Not a drawing"): Exit Sub
strFilename = swModel.GetPathName
strFilename = "G:\45 Design\" & Mid(strFilename, InStrRev(strFilename, "\") + 1, InStrRev(strFilename, ".") - InStrRev(strFilename, "\")) & "pdf"
MsgBox "Save path : " & strFilename
swModel.Extension.SaveAs strFilename, 0, 0, Nothing, 0, 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The message isn't necessary as I'm trying to make my code be invisible and fully automatic, but regardless... thanks!